# JQuery - live sending of form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use the live() class to send a form?

I have dynamically generated forms surrounding various items on a page when clicked I want to submit the form and display the results in fancybox following is my code, which doesnt submit anything -

```
                $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
                    type: "GET", 
                    url: "code.xml", 
                    dataType: "xml", 
                    success: parseXml, 
                    error: errorMsg, 
                    complete: alldone
            }); 
            function alldone() {
                setTimeout(function() {
// do stuff


                $(function() {

                    $("#albums_carousel").carouFredSel({
                    curcular: false,
                    infinite: false,
                    auto : false,
                    prev : {    
                        button  : "#prevAlb",
                        key     : "left"
                    },
                    next : { 
                        button  : "#nextAlb",
                        key     : "right"
                    },
                    pagination  : "#pagerAlbums"
        });
                    $("#games_carousel").carouFredSel({
                    curcular: false,
                    infinite: false,
                    auto : false,
                    prev : {    
                        button  : "#prevG",
                        key     : "left"
                    },
                    next : { 
                        button  : "#nextG",
                        key     : "right"
                    },
                    pagination  : "#pagerGames"
        });
                    $("#tracks_carousel").carouFredSel({
                    curcular: false,
                    infinite: false,
                    auto : false,
                    prev : {    
                        button  : "#prev3",
                        key     : "left"
                    },
                    next : { 
                        button  : "#next3",
                        key     : "right"
                    },
                    pagination  : "#pagerTracks"
        });





        });}, 100);

            }
            function parseXml(xml) 
            { 
                    $('.albRow').empty(); 
                    $(xml).find("album").each(function() 
                    { 
                            var title = $(this).find('productDescription').text();
                            var artist = $(this).find('artist').text();
                            var artwork = $(this).find('artwork').text(); 
                            var price = $(this).find('price').text();
                            var mediaItem = $(this).find('mediaItem').text();
                            var artwork = $(this).find('artwork').text();
                            var chargeCode = $(this).find('chargecode').text();
                            var productCode = $(this).find('productCode').text();
                            var listItem = $('<li><form action="https://formhandler.net" method="post" id="pfi_form'+mediaItem+'" name="pfi_form" target="thisframe"><input type="hidden" name="transactionRequest" id="pfi_transactionRequest" value="' + chargeCode + '"><input type="hidden" name="productCode" id="pfi_productCode" value="' +productCode+'"><input type="hidden" name="productDescription" id="pfi_productDescription" value="'+title+'"><scr'+"i"+'pt type="text/javascript" src="formFooter.js"> </scr'+"i"+'pt><a id="inline" name="pfi_form'+mediaItem+'" class="overlayLink" href="#data"><img src="'+artwork+'" width="82" height="85" alt="Buy Adele 21" /></a><span class="artist">Adele</span><span class="title">21</a></span><span class="price"><a id="inline" href="#data">£1.60</a> </span></li></form>');                               
                            $(".albRow").append(listItem);
                    });
            }
            function errorMsg() { 
                    alert("error getting xml feed"); 
            } 
         });



          $('.overlayLink').live('click', function() {

$("a#inline").fancybox({'hideOnContentClick': true});

$.fancybox({

    type: "iframe"
})

 $("#pfi_form3022158").submit();

})


    </script>
```

Any ideas would be very gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: This must be a very small fragment of your code. I don't see a form at all. Are you sure that the form *ID* is set correctly? You name your variable `formName`, but a name won't help you when you use the id selector in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For what i've seen from your code you could have done:

```
    $('.overlayLink').live('click', function() {

    $("a#inline").fancybox({'hideOnContentClick': true});

    $.fancybox({

        type: "iframe"
    })

     $(this).closest('form').submit();

    })
```